# Remove everything

Tags: git

I want to remove everything inside my git project. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole project?

Comment: drop the server hd from the 30th floor... that will do it. :)

Comment: Not the project, only the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah. Just like you can add everything.

```
git rm -r .
```

Comment: I'm getting "fatal: pathspec '' did not match any files" on Linux/Windows. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I saw that my working folder is empty now. So it worked now? What a stupid error message!!

My local copy is ok now. But what about the original copy on the server. Do I need to something else?

Sorry, I red lots of documents but it's still confusing me.

Comment: To empty the remote repo, you need to commit that. `git commit -m "you all, go away"` and then push. `git push`

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
rm -rf /path/to/gitrepo
```

Or did you mean 'Remove all files in the project from content tracking'?

```
git rm -r /path/to/gitrepo
git commit
```

Comment: Yeah, I want them to be accessible in the previous version. But the new version shouldn't have them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely remove the repo from GitHub, there is "Delete this repository" option for that on the project admin page.  The URL is typically something like:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<project>/edit
```

If you want to remove the files from the next revision of the repo, but keep their histories, then you should do something like:

```
git rm -r .
```

If you only want to eliminate the history of certain files in the repo, you can use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

Comment: No, I still want to keep those files in previous version. But the new version will not have them.